# Column doesn't exist error when trying to insert new value to table (on heroku using nodejs and pg library)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku-postgres

I'm playing with an app on heroku. It uses heroku postgresql but I have trouble inserting data to it.
The code looks as follows:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

function connect2DB(){
  const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });
  client.connect();
  return client;
}

function createLastUseTableIfNotThere(){
  try{
    const client = connect2DB();
    client.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "lastUse" ("clientKey" VARCHAR(255), "lastDate" date, PRIMARY KEY ("clientKey"));', (err, res) => {
      if(err){
        console.error(`createLastUseTableIfNotThere db query failed!`);
        console.error(err);
      }else{
        console.log(res);
      }
      client.end();
    });
  } catch(e){
    console.error(`createLastUseTableIfNotThere failed!`);
    console.error(e);
  }
}

function lastUseMiddleware(req, res, next){
  const clientKeyValue = req.context.clientKey;
  try{
    if(clientKeyValue != undefined){
      console.log(`lastUseMiddleware: upserting clientKey ${clientKeyValue}`);
      const client = connect2DB();
      client.query(`
        INSERT INTO "lastUse"("clientKey","lastDate")
        VALUES("${clientKeyValue}",now())
        ON CONFLICT ("clientKey")
        DO UPDATE SET "lastDate" = now();`,
        (err, res) => {
          if(err){
            console.error(`lastUseMiddleware: upserting failed!`);
            console.error(err);
          }
          client.end();
      });
    }else{
      console.warn(`lastUseMiddleware: clientKey is undefined: ${clientKey}`);
    }
  }catch(e){
    console.error(`lastUseMiddleware thrown`);
    console.error(e);
  }
  next();
}
```

Calling the `createLastUseTableIfNotThere` function worked properly and I can see the table created on heroku.
Calling the `lastUseMiddleware` function generates following errors in logs:

> lastUseMiddleware: upserting clientKey 3f825846-791c-3c5b-8916-4e2c827165b2

> lastUseMiddleware: upserting failed!

> error: column "3f825846-791c-3c5b-8916-4e2c827165b2" does not exist.

My intention is to add new row to the table with given clientKey and current date.
Looks like the clientKey is treated as column identifier.
Any idea why it is like that?
Maybe the `clientKey` field should not be used as primary key in the table?

Comment: Apparently your code encloses string values with double quotes (`"`), but in SQL strings have to be enclosed in single quotes `'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres treats double quotes as columns. You could use single column.

Like,

```
VALUES('${clientKeyValue}',now())
```

Comment: `s/single column/single quote/`